# unload event in js with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to fire off an AJAX request before a page unloads using the unlaod event and jQuery:

```
jQuery(window).on("unload", function(event) {        
     SaveSettings();//makes an ajax request with the 'async' property set to false
});
```

This works fine in IE9 and FF10, but in the webkit browsers (chrome and safari specifically), the event is called, but the AJAX request is never completed.  I am setting jQuery's AJAX call to synchronous (i realise this may "hold up" the browser but it should be quick!).  I even tried binding directly to the window.onbeforeunload event, but with the same results.  I would think that a synchronous request to a webservice should prevent the browser from closing before the call is complete, right?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own I don't think it is as easy and you'd think

Comment: Ive read it, i cant seem to get it to work.  Whats funny is that for some reason i want to say it used to work till I updated Chrome.